# In Ubuntu Server 16.04, what partition type should I use for system space?

Tags: server, partitioning

I am setting up a server using Ubuntu Server 16.04 and I have 5 GB of free space on my drive that I want to partition into space used for installing the system. What option should I select under "How to use this partition:"? These options include (but are not limited to) Ext4 journaling file system, FAT16 file system, EFI System Partition and Reserved BIOS Boot Area. There are 15 options, including "do not use the partition". Which should I select?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your system partition chose `Ext4 journaling file system`

For your swap partition of course the `swap area` file system

Answer (score 0):

EXT4, obviously, if the goal is to install Ubuntu but even for the server variant without DE, 5GB may not be enough.